# Samba File Server hide folders for certain users

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, samba, smb

I have a Ubuntu machine with the following folders.

[image: folders]

I am using samba server to share the folder.

I have 3users:


 user 1 = full access

user 2 = access to folder music (only read)

user 3 = access to folder school (only read)

I want to be prompted to log in when you try to access the folder Shared.
If user 1 sings in he gets to view all the folders. If user 2 signs in he only gets to see the folder music. And if user 3 sings in he only can see the folder school.

So the idea is to hide folders for users that are not allowed to see those. How can you configure this using samba server.

**EDIT:** If they can't read the content of the folders it's also okay, if hiding folders isn't possible or harder to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it duplicates a question asked and answered on askubuntu.com and by all rights belongs there rather than here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already wrote a solution for your problem at askubuntu.com


https://askubuntu.com/a/531476/333893

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this page for more information: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html

It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this official manual can help you https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/